# Embedding PDF into exe and open it via hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, hyperlink, resources

in my WPF application i want to embed some pdf files which can be opened by clicking on a hyperlink.
I dont want to put them into bin/debug because the user shall not access the files directly. I want to embed them into the exe file.

So i added a new Folder in my Project and called it 'Help' I added a file called 'myHelpFile.pdf' and set the build action to 'resource'.

Now i added the following XAML code to my WPF:

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink Click="open_help_onClick">
            <TextBlock Text="Help"/> 
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

and in the code behind i added:

```
private void open_help_onClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/Resources/Help/myHelpFile.pdf");
```

}

Its obvious that the link is not correct. But how has it to be set?

Comment: `Process.Start` is like opening `start->run` or typing directly into the command line so of course it's not going to work like that since "resources/Help/myHelpFile.pdf" will mean nothing to it. I'm not a wpf person but I think you're going to have to extract the embedded resource and write it to disk somewhere (ie output folder or the temp folder) in order to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I will look after that!